# How would a PHP backdoor affect a Windows system if the file isn't executed?

Tags: wordpress, windows, malware

Windows Defender warned of malware during an FTP download from one of my WP sites that has been compromised.  The warning points to:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=Backdoor%3APHP%2FWebshell.G!MSR&threatid=2147760277

WD quarantined the various files it flagged.

My question is:  If you never execute these files on a Windows system, how could the code be a threat?  If all I do is open them in VS Code or Notepad++.

I want try to forensically study the entire `public_html` directory to learn about how this was done, etc. That said, not interested in compromising my system either.

Comment: Defender want to prevent you even from downloading any malicious file so that you accidentally won't run it. If you study malware, instruct Defender to ignore scanning your study folder.